# All defined jobs on jenkins at cloudbees disappeared

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I've been using cloudbees Jenkins to build and test my open source project. Development of the project was stopped for a few months, there wasn't any commits that can trigger jobs (several jobs were defined).

Today I noticed that all my jobs disappeared (https://ragnor.ci.cloudbees.com/). Why all my jobs were removed? Maybe because of inactivity? Is there any way how I can restore the jobs?

Comment: Your account has been restored. Please open a support ticket if you need further assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an infrastructure issue a few weeks ago that impacted a small number of customers who brought their accounts out of hibernation during an outage.

We have corrected the configuration issue for most accounts, but there were a few that slipped through the cracks (like yours).

As per the comment earlier by Ivan, this is now resolved for your account.